# How do I use fs.write?

Tags: fs

I'm making a Chrome Extension that will allow the user to choose the background image of their blank tab. I have the button element in my HTML file setup and I have some javasciript random number generators; 
tl:dr I don't need help with the HTML or JS for the most part, but in my `manifest.json` file I the browser recognizes the image I call in there, for example if I want the background image to be `image1.png` I call `"default_icon": "image1.png",` but in order for the user to be able to change what image they use, I need to be able to change this. So when they click the `<button>` labeled `image2.png` I need to use `fs.write` to change the value of `"default_icon":`. But I don't know how to use `fs.write`

Comment: what did you try all ready please share your code

Comment: haven't tried anything

Comment: so please before asking to go and read  the documentation see few examples of the API (that is really well documented and after showing a little bit of research) ask for help